# Symfony 2 Error using Forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, twig

I've got a big problem with symfony 2, and forms

I've followed this instruction...

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

The firsth class is (like TAG):

```
class TipoPermessoFerie {
    public $id;
    public $nome;
    public $descrizione;
    public $permesso;
}
```

Then I coded the container class (TASK):

```
class Form1 {
    protected $descrizione;
    protected $tipoPermessoFerie; // ArrayCollection of TipoPermessoFerie

    // metodi

    public function __construct(){
        $this->tipoPermessoFerie = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getDescrizione () {
        return $this->descrizione;
    }

    public function setDescrizione ($de) {
        $this->descrizione = $de;
    }

    // get un ArrayCollection
    public function getTipoPermessoFerie () {
        return $this->tipoPermessoFerie;
    }

}
```

and the the 2 wrapper classes(TAGTYPE and TASKTYPE):

```
class TipoPermessoFerieType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('nome');
        $builder->add('descrizione');
        $builder->add('permesso');
        $builder->add('id');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TipoPermessoFerie',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'tipopermessoferie';
    }
}

class Form1Type extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('descrizione');
        $builder->add('tipoPermessoFerie', 'collection', array('type' => new TipoPermessoFerieType()));
        $builder->setMethod('GET');
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => '< Fase 2 >'));
        $builder->add('reset', 'reset', array('label' => '< Annulla >'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Form1',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'form1';
    }
}
```

The controller works like this

```
$repos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:TipoPermessoFerie');
    $tipiF = $repos->findBy(array('permesso' => 'F')); // many
    ...
    dump($tipiF); //this is ok  
    $f1 = New Form1 ();
    $f1->setDescrizione("Fase 1");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tipiF); $i++) {
        dump($tipiF[$i]); //OK
        $f1->getTipoPermessoFerie()->add($tipiF[$i]);
    }

    dump($f1); //f1 is istance of Form1
    $form = $this->createForm(new Form1Type(), $f1);
```

******** at this point i've got an error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   AppBundle\Entity\TipoPermessoFerie. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to
>   "AppBundle\Entity\TipoPermessoFerie" or by adding a view transformer
>   that transforms an instance of class
>   AppBundle\Entity\TipoPermessoFerie to scalar, array or an instance of
>   \ArrayAccess.
>
> ```
> ...  
> $form->handleRequest($request);
> ```

I don't know what's wrong....

May someone help me, please?

Comment: Could share the code of your ->createFrom() controller method, too?

Comment: I didn't define a method createForm... Do i have to create a specific method? Where can i find information about this?